# More Room for Ubuntu - How do I use GParted to Make Ubuntu Partition Bigger

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, gparted

I have been using Ubuntu for a few years now, but am now faced with running out of space for the Ubuntu partition on the newest desktop that I built.  Both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS are on a 500GB NVME drive.  I use GRUB to access the different operating systems.

I have made an up-to-date Ubuntu USB drive with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I have made a full backup of the Windows 10 partition.  I have also backed up the few files that I don’t want to loose on the Ubuntu partition.

As you can see, I only allocated 15GB for Ubuntu and it is currently at 95% and I receive warnings about running out of space.

[image]

My question is how do I use Gparted from the Live USB drive to increase the space for Ubuntu?
Do I have to increase the device above where I freed up space and move it up to where I can attach it to my Ubuntu partition? Is there an easier way?  I have freed up 97.66GB that is currently unallocated.  Both partitions seem to be working well.

Thank you for any input or direction to where this was previously answered.  I did a search and couldn’t find out if I just have to move it up and then merge it, make it smaller, until I climb up to the Ubuntu partition at the top.  I was hoping for an easier way!

Comment: Another alternative is to create a new partition for /home and move /home to that partition. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving
 I might add the swap space to / (root) as that is easy, and either create new swap in the unallocated or change to use swap file.  But if you delete swap, also change UUID  of swap in fstab to new swap or comment out mount of swap in fstab, temporarily or you will have boot issue.

Comment: It is safer to shrink Windows partition usin Windows Disk Manager than GParted. See https://superuser.com/questions/1370229/unable-to-resize-system-partition-using-gparted Here is info from the GParted site: http://joejanuszk.com/blog/increasing-ubuntu-partition-size-dual-boot-windows/

Comment: Thank you for your input.

It seems it would be a lot easier and a lot safer just to use the 100GB unallocated partition to load Ubuntu.  Thank you again for your input.

Answer (score 0):

That is going to take a LONG time and it is going to warn you that it is risky because it has to move 3 partitions to the right (the swap and two microsoft partitions)... If the unallocated space was on the right directly next to the partition you wanted to grow, then it ('shifting it to the left') would go fairly fast and with less risk.... BUT it is an NVME, so I really dont know how long that would take there...

in gparted right clicking on the partition you want to resize and selecting "resize/move", should allow you to grow it to the size you want(based on the unallocated space on the drive).

**To answer your question:** Since I last used gparted I don't remember if you can just be on partition 1 and gparted just recognizes there to be some space between partition 6 and 7 and you can just grow it using that space. If it does work that way now then pretty easy, you just type the new size of the partition... But if not, I think you have to step through moving the unallocated space until it is adjacent to the right of the ubuntu partiton.

...moving the space, by setting the "free space preceding" to the size of the unallocated space.... (once for each of the 3 partitions, starting with the one to the left, adjacent to the unallocated space)

(**just me personally**, when I do things like that I try to get rid of or rebuild the stuff I can do without to save time... like I would delete the swap and leave 4 gigs in the unallocated space and rebuild it there afterwards. No need to wait to copy swap from one place to another... ESPECIALLY on a spinning drive. Another time I was too scared too risk moving such a large partition so I dd'ed the ubuntu partition into the larger partition i created in the unallocated space... some changes in grub entries,fstab, and blkid were involved but that warning message spooked me on that particular system)